# Is there any other way, I checked permission on a user in an optimize way in marklogic?

Tags: permissions, marklogic, roles, user-roles

```
let $permissions := perm:get-permissions($uri)  (:function to check permission on document, return sec:permission node:)    
if ($value) then 
    let $user-roles := xdmp:get-current-roles()
    return
        if (exists($permissions[sec:capability=('insert', 'update') and 
            sec:role-id = $user-roles]) or $user-roles eq 
            xdmp:role("admin")) then
         (:xml node:)
        else
            fn:error()
else 
     xdmp:document-insert() (:throw error if the user have no permssion to insert the document:)
```

Is there any better way to optimise this code?
Here, I need to check whether a user have any type update permission with them.

Comment: Why are you looking to manually perform a permission check for insert/update and conditionally throw an error? Why not just let them attempt to insert/update, and if they don't have permissions it will throw? Or are you looking to test whether they have certain permissions and then return something else?

Comment: Yes, you are are right I have to check certain permissions and on the basis of that I am returning the error and insertion of document is other flow of the code, where It automatically throw error , when the user have not permissions to insert the doc.